# Cursor synchronization in multiple charts that don't fit in viewport height

Tags: reactjs, recharts

On my page I have multiple charts and they don't fit in viewport height. They also have synchronized active cursors and every time I hover over one of the charts, the page scrolls down and up like Recharts trying to show all of synchronized charts at same time in one window. What's the posible solution to the problem if you encountered on this one before?

Here's [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-tdd-drldhd?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue. Probably will have to remove syncid from one of charts.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).